# starting new activity and keep previous activity processing

Tags: android, android-activity

My MainActivity is receiving a string("yes" or "no") from arduino via bluetooth and I want to display a fullscreem picture when I receive "no" and display another one if I receive "yes". The arduino send at first "no".

In my MainActivity I have:

```
public void run(){
Intent intent;
if(strInput.equals("non")){
   intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Danger.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Danger.class:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.danger);
    if (MainActivity.getstrInput().equals("yes")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Danger.Class, Safe.Class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    }
```

My question is how keep reading the inputstream in the Danger.class whereas 
the MainActivity is stopped when I start another activity. It means I want 
that the MainActivity keep reading input while the picture is displayed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to process in async task and start other activity\

Comment: Sounds like you should read input via a service and then let activities get readings from that service. Alternatively you could let danger be a fragment instead so that you never leave the main activity.

Comment: This is not how you are supposed to work with activities, as soon as you start a new Activity the old one is paused and then stopped and it can possibly be destroyed by the system, so following @cYrixmorten's advice I would recommend you to use Service for that - you can find some guides in the [developer portal](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)